# Call extern C function from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, bootloader, boot, osdev

I'm new at osdev, and i made a simple bootsector that activates the a20 gate and enters protected mode.
I'm triyng to call an external C function, but my bootsector code is assembled with `nasm -f bin boot.asm` (bin doesn't support extern calls)
I'm using `gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c` to compile the C file.

I tried to use extern functions, but i'm using BIN filetype.
I researched about, and found that it is possible to load the kernel memory address with `int 13h`, but I couldn't do it

Comment: Related: [OSDev BareBones tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones)